# xlsxwriter: is there a way to define a "named cell"?

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

[In excel](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-HA010342417.aspx) you can name a cell or range of cells. This "named cell" is especially useful in formulas. For example `=countif(EmployeeStatus, "Full Time")` is much more descriptive than `=countif($B$2:$B$102, "Full Time")`.

Is this functionality built into xlsxwriter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*No, I don't believe it is. I'm not seeing it in the documentation anywhere. https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/working_with_cell_notation.html
The "Cell Utility Functions" don't include it.
Probably would be good to put in a feature request for it.*

## Update

They posted on [github](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/181) the way to do this. (It uses the Workbook, not the Cells, so I was looking in the wrong place for it.)

> That is possible in XlsxWriter using the workbook define_name()
>   method, see the [docs](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/workbook.html#workbook-define-name) and the [example program](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/blob/master/examples/defined_name.py).

And the example in the docs is:

```
workbook.define_name('Sales', '=Sheet1!$G$1:$H$10')
```